# Separate file name from its path

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

I have a number of files from this expression:

```
ui_files := $(wildcard $(SUBDIRS:%=%/*.ui)).
```

Now I need the list of the same file paths, but with "ui_" prefix in file name and another extension (.h). How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the list using [`foreach`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Foreach-Function) and transform each element:

```
h_files := $(foreach ui,$(ui_files),$(dir $(ui))ui_$(notdir $(ui:.ui=.h)))
```

Or, first transform the whole list and then use [`join`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#File-Name-Functions):

```
h_files := $(join $(dir $(ui_files)),$(patsubst %.ui,ui_%.h,$(notdir $(ui_files))))
```

Both solutions use [`dir` and `notdir`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#File-Name-Functions) functions.

Comment: @itun it's just a name of iteration variable (see `foreach` docs), you're free to give it another name.