# make target and dependency name formating

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

You can see the first problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048402/separate-file-name-from-its-path), it was solved, thx Eldar Abusalimov. Now I need to put right targets and dependencies for uic.exe call.
The beginning of the code is:

```
ui_files := $(wildcard $(SUBDIRS:%=%/*.ui))
ui_headers := $(foreach ui_files,$(ui_files),$(dir $(ui_files))ui_$(notdir $(ui_files:.ui=.h)))
ui_cpp := $(patsubst %.h, %.cpp, $(ui_headers))
```

First, I need to do is to generate headers what I was trying to do by this code:

```
<directory/ui_<ui_file_name>.h>: <ui_file_path>
    $(QT_BIN)/uic -o $@ $<
```

Second, I generate cpps :

```
<directory/ui_<ui_file_name>.cpp>: <ui_file_path> <header_file_path>
$(QT_BIN)/uic -i <header_file_path> -o <target> <ui_file_path>
```

Help me please, to fill this not-make syntax by make syntax or give me an appropriate method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it should be something like this (however, I'm not sure, how Make will deal with directory part of the files):

```
$(ui_headers) : ui_%.h : %.ui
    $(QT_BIN)/uic -o $@ $< 

$(ui_cpp) : %.cpp : %.ui ui_%.h
    $(QT_BIN)/uic -i $(word 2,$^) -o $@ $<
```

Both rules are [static pattern](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern) rules.

### UPD.

Static pattern rule are not good here, because the pattern is applied to the whole file name (with a path). Instead, one should use regular [pattern rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules):

```
ui_%.h : %.ui
    $(QT_BIN)/uic -o $@ $< 

%.cpp : %.ui ui_%.h
    $(QT_BIN)/uic -i $(word 2,$^) -o $@ $<
```

[How Patterns Match](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Match) chapter explains how does it work:

> When the target pattern does not contain a slash (and it usually does not), directory names in the file names are removed from the file name before it is compared with the target prefix and suffix. After the comparison of the file name to the target pattern, the directory names, along with the slash that ends them, are added on to the prerequisite file names generated from the pattern rule's prerequisite patterns and the file name. The directories are ignored only for the purpose of finding an implicit rule to use, not in the application of that rule.

Comment: Make will paste "ui_" prefix before directory, not before file name. So it is wrong.